# Однородны ли члены предложения?

Tags: запятые, однородные-члены

Как правильно расставить запятые в предложении с такой структурой: **На поляне летали жёлтые бабочки(,) и одна красная.** Это однородные члены предложения? Или лучше просто поменять его на **На поляне летали жёлтые и одна красная бабочки**.

Comment: А можно узнать, откуда это предложение?  Вряд ли оно из художественной литературы - таких моделей в языке просто нет, поэтому и  грамматика выглядит некорректно.  Соответственно, рассуждать об однородности членов (каких?) просто не имеет смысла.  Но если закрыть глаза на некорректную грамматику, то откуда берутся сомнения в однородности при наличии соединительного союза И? Считать  союз И присоединительным вряд ли получится.

Comment: Читала что-то детям из интернета, не могу вспомнить и найти в истории браузера. Не художественная литература, вы правы. Меня смутило предложение из-за паузы, которую вы обсуждали ниже в комментариях. Показалось, что нужна запятая или другое построение предложения. И, кстати, по поводу "над" поляной я даже не подумала тогда, а сейчас это кажется более удачным вариантом. Просто всё утро тогда крутила предложение в голове, никак оно мне покоя не давало :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Мне не кажется, что нужно что-то менять (***одна красная бабочки*** звучит не лучшим образом). Подлежащие в разном числе однородны, и в этом нет ничего "запрещенного", запятая перед ***и*** не нужна (если только автор не задумал каких-либо выкрутасов с присоединением неожиданной информации к вполне привычной, однообразной картине *летающих желтых бабочек*, но в таком случае и запятой было бы мало).

Примеры не совсем соответствуют исходному предложению, но всё же...

*Среди них были три девочки и один мальчик.* [В. М. Зензинов. Нена (1925)]

*Куклы были одеты в костюмы, сшитые из ярких шелковых лент: девки и парни, женщины и мужчины и один лысый старик с имамской бородой и с кинжалом.* [Давид Маркиш. Стать Лютовым. Вольные фантазии из жизни писателя Исаака Бабеля // «Октябрь», 2001]

*За обедом, исключая хозяйки и меня, сидели четыре женщины и один мужчина, и вот кто они были.* [Ф. Ф. Вигель. Записки (1850-1860)]

Answer (score 2):

Читая данное предложение в первый раз, я естественным образом использую в первой части возрастающую интонацию (с пиком на слове *бабочки*), в результате которой после слова *бабочки* ожидаю какого-то интонационного перехода и знака препинания. Не увидев ни того ни другого, я в замешательстве возвращаюсь к началу предложения и понимаю, что основное ударение в первой части должно падать на слово *жёлтые*, и тогда всё прочитывается правильно. Я предполагаю, судя по вопросу о запятой, что Юлия испытывает те же сомнения при прочтении данного предложения.

Если ввести в замешательство читателя было целью автора (что иногда может потребоваться, наверное), тогда ничего менять не нужно. Ещё возможно, что правильную интонацию задаёт общий контекст (хотя я затрудняюсь придумать такой контекст).

Есть несколько способов направить естественную интонацию в нужное русло:

На поляне летали несколько [много и т.п.] жёлтых бабочек и одна красная.
На поляне летали жёлтые и одна красная бабочки.
На поляне летали бабочки — жёлтые и одна красная.
И т.д.

В литературе встречается множество подобных примеров, но в процессе поиска я не смог найти ни одного примера, построенного по тому шаблону, который предложен в вопросе.

PS. Некоторые сомнения у меня вызывает правильность выражения "летать на поляне". Не думаю, чтобы мне такое встречалось в литературе — я бы сказал "летать над поляной".

Comment: Точно, если есть крылья, то нужно летать над поляной. "Над поляной порхали бабочки, роились мухи и жучки". [Г. П. Данилевский. Сожженная Москва (1885)] Мне тоже не понравилось "на поляне", но смутил словарь, где поляна называлась пространством.  ПОЛЯНА, . 1. Небольшое, заросшее травой, открытое пространство среди леса, кустарников; лужайка.

Comment: Интересно вы пишете про интонацию. Если в простом предложении нет знаков, то оно неизбежно делится на две части (повышение тона, понижение тона), пауза очень короткая, произносительная, обозначает перелом интонации.  А вот место деления читающий выбирает сам. Если получается, то это интонационно корректное предложение. Больше там ничего не придумаешь.

Comment: @Sharon Конечно, предложение интонационно корректное. Со второго раза (когда уже известна полная структура предложения) любой человек прочитает его правильно. Я вижу проблему в первом прочтении, до возможности провести полный анализ. Вполне возможно, что читатель, который часто сталкивается с таким построением, не будет испытывать затруднений. Но тогда у меня вопрос: где он мог часто с ним сталкиваться?

Comment: @Sharon Хочу уточнить: у Вас при первом беглом прочтении основное ударение падает на *жёлтые* или на *бабочки*? Если Вы успеваете "боковым зрением" забежать вперёд и проанализировать (что не исключено), тогда считаете ли Вы, что средний читатель (типа меня) тоже должен быть на это способен?

Comment: При первом прочтении я собираюсь поставить  ударение на "бабочках" перед союзом И, но предложение очень короткое, и уже ясно, что такая интонация неверна.  В данном случае средний читатель быстро найдет правильный интонационный вариант и догадается о некорректной стилистике.  Но в распространенном предложении он дольше бы  блуждал  от конца к началу.

Comment: А кстати, почему это в словаре поляну назвали пространством? Разве это верно? Вы, как математик, наверное, разбираетесь в пространствах и плоскостях.

Comment: @Sharon Не знаю. Вероятно, "пространство" имеется в виду в значении "промежуток между чем-то и чем-то" (здесь "среди чего-то"). Словарная статья про "пространство" у Кузнецова не совсем удачная (она даже грамотой не открывается почему-то). Но обычное посевное поле он не называет "пространством" (в отличие от других словарей). В общем, сложный вопрос, и по нему наверняка есть специальная литература.

Comment: @Sharon Скажите, пожалуйста, без обиняков — Вы считаете стилистику этого предложения приемлемой? Почему такое нигде не встречается? Все приведенные мной варианты исправления я встречал многократно.

Comment: Конечно. Я всегда говорю без  этих,  ну без обиняков. Приведенное предложение я считаю стилистически неверным, но это же надо доказывать ссылками на источник.   С моей же точки зрения некорректность заключается в использовании только одного числительного в определенных конструкциях. Можно сказать:  летали пять желтых  и три красных бабочки.  Согласованность слов  по числу (с учетом их позиции) тоже надо учитывать, то есть нежелательно:  летали пять желтых  и одна красная бабочка.

Comment: У вас хороши два варианта:  Над поляной летали несколько жёлтых бабочек и одна красная. Над поляной летали бабочки — жёлтые и одна красная (при обособлении, а также при дистантном расположении  определительный оборот ведет себя более свободно).